# Não consigo acessar o conteúdo estático no spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Como faço para acessar o conteúdo estático do spring-mvc? Por exemplo um css.

Tenho a seguinte configuração do spring:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    System.out.println("WebMvcConfigurerAdapter: addResourceHandlers");

    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
      .addResourceLocations("(/resources/");    
}

@Autowired
private Environment env;

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}


private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}


@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}


}
```

Esse também:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletSpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{MvcConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}

}
```

Na página eu tento acessar desse jeito:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />">
```

Essas são as pastas do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troca `.addResourceLocations("(/resources/");`, por `.addResourceLocations("/resources/");`

Comment: Foi isso mesmo.Obrigado!

Comment: Marque como respondida.